# The Krull-Schmidt-Remak Theorem for Semigroups and Monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid, finite-semigroups

For finite groups, the [Krull-Schmidt-Remak-Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem) holds, i.e. if
$$
 H_1 \times H_2 \times \ldots \times H_k \cong G_1 \times G_2 \times \ldots \times G_l
$$
where the $H_i, G_i$ could not be further decomposed, then $k = l$ and there exists a reordering $\pi : \{1,\ldots,k\}\to \{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that $H_i \cong G_{\pi(i)}$.

> Does the same hold for finite semigroups, or finite monoids?